# Detect Activity/BroadcastReceiver in Android Application.onCreate() method

Tags: java, android

I need to detect if Activity or BroadcastReceiver starts the application - inside of Application.onCreate method. Call `tryLoginOffline()` should not be in case of the application is started by broadcast receiver.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if(calledByActivity) {
            tryLoginOffline();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I need to detect if Activity or BroadcastReceiver starts the application - inside of Application.onCreate method.

Sorry, but there is no option for that.

> Call tryLoginOffline() should not be in case of the application is started by broadcast receiver.

Then that code should not be in an `Application` subclass' `onCreate()` method. Call it from your activity.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to put it to Activity because I want to avoid of calling launcher guest activity in case of user is already logged in and starts the app again. Therefore I tried to start member activity directly from Application component. But now the problem is that every BroadcastReceiver is launching the member Activity as well.

Comment: @robert.little: "Therefore I tried to start member activity directly from Application component" -- starting an activity from `onCreate()` of an `Application` is not a good plan, even ignoring your `BroadcastReceiver` scenario.